# there is always appear to me when i build

Tags: android

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: G:\ProjectsClone\MessengerClone\app\google-services.json
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: not well-formed (invalid token).","sources":[{"file":"G:\\ProjectsClone\\MessengerClone\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_weather.xml","position":{"startLine":53}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date

Comment: The file activity_weather.xml is mis-formed, probably a missing closing xml tag. Post the contents of it so we can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the issue here is exactly what the error message says:

"Could not find google-services.json".

If not already done, you need to download this json file from your Firebase console and place it in app folder.

Comment: i actually added google-services.json in right placeand still same problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your file `activity_weather.xml`. The error is `not well formed` which means that the XML structure isn't correct, most likely a closing tag missing somewhere.